# About Bootstrap column minute adjustment width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Following the title, consider this picture

[image: Screenshot rendered html]

I hope the right column could close to left area

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-2">
            platform Name
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-default" data-width="auto" >
            <option>123</option>
            <option>456</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfYAj.png

Comment: If you want your inputs to be next to your words, don't use columns.  Because that isn't how columns work.

Answer (score 0):

As Daedalus suggested, and if you use the inline horizontal form class you could tweak the padding/margin of the form elements to suit your needs..